Enum, default value reseted to nil on save
In a RoR 7.1.3 application using PostgreSQL, I've a enum defined as:
create_enum :foo_states, %i[active inactive]

create_table :foo do |t|
  t.enum :state, enum_type: :foo_states, default: :active, null: false
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  enum :state, %i[active inactive], default: :active, validate: true
end

When I instanciate a new object it works fine:
Foo.new
=> #<Foo state: "active">

Foo.create(state: :bar).errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors [#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=state, type=inclusion, ...

But when saving records it does not persist its state:
foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo state: "active">

foo.save
=> #<Foo state: nil>

# same on .create
Foo.create
=> #<Foo state: nil>

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, how am I using this feature incorrectly?

Note that you should seriously consider if you want to use an integer or a string instead of an enum column. The big problem with enum type columns is that you can't really add or delete states whithout changing the table DDL. So they are only actually useful if the number of possible states is truely finate and known when you're designing the schema (and how often does that actually pan out?).

Indeed, it seems quite cumbersome to remove values from database-defined enums. Plus, I don't really need blazing fast performances (I'm not expecting many records on this index). Thanks for pointing this out, very educative as usual !

You create enum in the database layer with active and inactive strings as possible values
But when you write in the model
enum :state, %i[active inactive], default: :active, validate: true

it means you will try to save 0 for active and 1 for inactive (index as integer)
Instead of this define enum in the model as hash such way
enum :state, { active: 'active', inactive: 'inactive' }, default: :active, validate: true

From the docs:

Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :status, [ :active, :archived ]
end

# conversation.update! status: 0
conversation.active!

Finally it’s also possible to use a string column to persist the enumerated value
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :status, active: "active", archived: "archived"
end


